# Quartz.Net registering jobs with DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.Net windows service to run remote jobs on MVC4 app with Castle windsor dependency injection. I want to schedule jobs that on execution reference model interfaces to access model functions.

Here is my Job class:

```
    public class MyJob: IJob 
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyJob));
        private readonly IQuartzModel _quartzModel;

        public MyJob(IQuartzModel quartzModel)
        {
           this._quartzModel = quartzModel;
        }

       public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
       {
            quartzModel.DoModelFunction();       
       }
  }
```

I create my own instance of IJobFactory like this:

```
public class WindsorJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public WindsorJobFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle)
    {
        if (bundle == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bundle");
        }
        return (IJob)_container.Resolve(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
    }
 }
```

I have created these registrations with castle DI

```
        IJobFactory jobFactory = new WindsorJobFactory(container);

        container.Register(Component.For<IJobFactory>().Instance(jobFactory));
        container.Register(Component.For<IQuartzModel>().ImplementedBy<QuartzModel>());

        var jobTypes = GetJobTypes();
        foreach (Type jobType in jobTypes)
        {
              container.Register(Component.For(jobType).ImplementedBy(jobType).LifeStyle.Transient);
        }

    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetJobTypes()
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => typeof(IJob).IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsInterface);
    }
```

Also I have registrations for scheduler service settings and QuartzTaskSchedulingService where I create IScheduler, ISchedulerFactory and StdSchedulerFactory instances and create jobs.

```
        container.Register(Component.For<IQuartzSchedulingServiceSettings>()
                        .UsingFactoryMethod(QuartzSchedulingServiceConfiguration.GetConfiguration)
                        .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);

        container.Register(Component.For<IQuartzTaskSchedulingService>()
                  .ImplementedBy<QuartzTaskSchedulingService>()
                  .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

When I try to execute MyJob I get the following error in my Quartz.Net windows service log:

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate type which has no empty constructor
```

If I execute MyJob without passing interface in constructor, It executes succesfully.

To run the job i initialize QuartzTaskSchedulingService from my controller and execute job creation method.  Inside QuartzTaskSchedulingService I have initializations of ISchedulerFactory, IScheduler. Inside constructor i use connection settings provided by IQuartzSchedulingServiceSettings to get instance of scheduler.

```
    public QuartzTaskSchedulingService(IQuartzSchedulingServiceSettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;

        Address = string.Format("tcp://{0}:{1}/{2}", settings.ServerAddress, settings.ServerPort, settings.SchedulerBindName);
        schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(GetProperties(Address, settings.ServerInstanceName));

            try
            {
                quartzScheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
                if (!quartzScheduler.IsStarted)
                {
                    quartzScheduler.Start();
                }
            }
      }
```

After that it jumps to job creation method

```
    public void TestJobShot(Type t)
    {

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create(t)
            .WithIdentity("MyJob", "Common")
            .RequestRecovery()
            .Build();

        var trigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("MyJob", "Common")
            .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")
            .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow)
            .WithPriority(1)
            .Build();

        quartzScheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

    }
```

It succesfully creates job and schedules it for execution from my AdoJobStore. As soon as it executes i get the following problem

I've tried numerous solutions to get this working, but all of them have ended unsuccesfuly
Am I missing some kind of DI registrations or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: could you please show how to you run the job ?

Comment: Cybermaxs - Betclic, I edited post to answer your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, IQuartzModel is not being resolved properly by you container. 
I had the same type of problems but using Autofac.